I want to pass a path in my groovy in jmeter
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()).getParent();)}

I have saved this in user defined variable
I need a path with / or //
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()).getParent();)}

This will give \ which will not work in Groovy in jmeter.
I need a path with /
I tried
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()).getParent().replaceAll("\\\\", "/");)}

also
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()).getParent().replace("\\", "/");)}

also
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()).getParent().replace('\u005C', '/');)}

but all three are not working


If you're referring the generated variable in form of ${myVar} in JSR223 Test Elements it will be interpreted "as is" and presence of characters requiring escaping will break your code and it won't compile. You should rather use vars shorthand like vars.get('myVar') instead

Using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern, since JMeter
3.1 you should be using Groovy for scripting

The same code can be used in Groovy directly, there is no need to put it into a JMeter Variable



More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
